# Problem of Flask append the result after render_template

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem with my Flask Application which is the render_template always append the result

This is my code for Flask:

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        state2 = request.form['state']

        with psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=twitah user=amz password=admin1234") as conn:
            with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) as cur:
                #negeri=state
                cur.execute("SELECT id,textt FROM tweet WHERE state = '%s';"%state2)
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                #print ("# Individual row values accessed via column name:")
                for i in range (cur.rowcount):
                    row = rows[i]
                    i=row['id']
                    u=row['textt']
                    idd.append(i)
                    dataa.append(u)


    return render_template('masuk.html', id=idd,data=dataa)
```

After running the `IP Address` the output in `masuk.html` always append with the previous one when tried with another return value.

Comment: what do you mean "the output in masuk.html always append with the previous one" ? Can you show us an example ?

Comment: also what is the expected output ? can you show an example ?

Comment: @reportgunner Let say: 1st time render template the output
"Ahmad Labu", "Ali Baba"

then render template again with another value (output only Pobla Yap) (refresh)
"Ahmad Labu", "Ali Baba", "Pobla Yap"

Comment: what is state2 and request.form['state'] ?

Comment: @reportgunner user will enter the state, and the /predict route will return the data from DB according to the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you define your variables idd and dataa? I guess that they are defined as global variables, stay in namespace between requests and they grow in size when you do those append methods. You should put

```
idd = []
dataa = []
```

in your predict() function.